# Do I need a DI to put a Guitar through my Interface?

Tags: audio-interfaces, guitar

I recently picked up an MBox 2 Mini so that we can send a guitar into our DAW and put effects onto the guitar in live time. I know that this will work with the configuration of software and interface hardware I will be using, however because of the nature of this recording work, I do not know how to feed the guitar into the interface. The interface has 2 inputs- A Line input (1/4" jack) and an XLR input for microphones, or if I had a DI, that too. What I want to know is if I could plug a guitar right into the line input, no amp or DI, or if I should be using a DI and using the XLR input on my interface. I realize that using a microphone with an amplifier is most times ideal, however because we want the sound to be as clean as possible when it goes into the computer, that would not work for us. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No DI needed. Just your 1/4" guitar cable straight to the "line in" on the MBox. The output of the guitar is an unbalanced line level signal. The MBox is designed to take that input on either input 1 or 2.

Page 34
[MBox 2 Mini Manual](http://akmedia.digidesign.com/support/docs/Mbox_2_Mini_Getting_Started_v73_32993.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

1/4 inch jack lead should do it. Just plug your guitar straight in. On my interface, it has 2 x Jack/XLR combo sockets(1616M).

Comment: I got the wording wrong. I read from the manual, but I was reading another question too, and mixed them up. Edited it now.